# Calculate difference between DateTime.Now and time(7) value in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a db that contains the schedule for employees reflecting when they should  clock in and out. When they punch in, for example, I want to compare the current time with what they're scheduled for.  For the life of me I can't seem to work it out.  I'm retrieving the scheduled time as so:

```
if (day=="Friday")
{
    var auth = from d in dc.Dailies
               where d.Number == employee
               select d.FridayStart; ;

}
```

Which seems fine but none of the examples I'm trying work... one possible problem seems that although I'm storing the scheduled times as `time(7)`, the query appears to return them as `TimeSpan` values, which puzzles me.

Comment: Well, `DateTime` in C# is usedwhen you have a date and a time. If you only have a time, you have a `TimeSpan`. By the name `time(7)` it appears it only stores time, not date, then it's converted to TimeSpan

Comment: I understand... the point is that I'm trying to compare say, if someone is scheduled to clock in at 9:00 (my time(7) value) and they're arriving at 9:30 based on DateTimeNow.TimeofDay I'm trying to calculate that difference.

Comment: your question is missing a lot of information that would be needed to help you.  e.g., your title mentions DateTime.Now  and calculating differences, but your example code neither references DateTime.Now nor shows any calculations nor comparisons.   You also mentione that none of the examples work, but you don't describe HOW they don't work.  That is, are you getting a runtime error?  Are more or fewer rows being returned than you expected? etc.  
Also, you should provide a "smallest possible" code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Whenever to time are subtracted the results is a TimeSpan() object.

Comment: Are all of your times using the same time zone? That will make a big difference in how you compare the times.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Let's say your time(7) is stored in the variable named `dbTime`, which is a TimeSpan. To get the difference between the stored time and the current, you could use `dtTime-DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`. This will return a TimeSpan with time difference. Or you could compare them with `dtTime==DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` (same time); `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay<dtTime` (it's not the time yet) ;`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay>dtTime` (the time has passed) and so on

Comment: Thank you @Magnetron , I get very flustered whenever I venture in here.  So, I've tried exactly what you're suggesting and I get:

"Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.TimeSpan?>' and 'System.TimeSpan'"

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase it this way... If I have a time(7) value that I'm trying to compare to DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, how can I do it?  Sorry, I find this venue very hard to navigate for a newcomer...

Comment: Is `FridayStart` the `time(7)` value?  Is this Microsoft SQL Server you're querying?

Comment: @MattJohnson, yes to both... thank you

Comment: Well, if you have a IQueryable, you don't have a TimeSpan, but a query, which returns many results, not a single one. For example, you could call `.ToList()` and convert it to a List or `.First()` and get the first result (that you can compare), or even iterate over it with foreach and compare each result. You should post the relevant piece of code here

Comment: Please update your question to include all the details instead of putting them in the comments, so everyone is clear what the code looks like and where it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from your code, you could do

```
if (day=="Friday")
{
    //auth is expected to be an IQueryable, which derives from IEnumerable, 
    //so it could be many results
    var auth = from d in dc.Dailies
               where d.Number == employee
               select d.FridayStart;

    //So, if you're expecting only one result, and guarantee that will be one,
    //you can use .First() or .Single()
    var timeDifference = auth.First() - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;    
}
```

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner!  Thank you so much!!!  So, if I can pick your brain for a tiny bit more help?  I want to return an absolute value and compare it in minutes, so if the difference is say greater than 30 minutes...

I'm very grateful... this isn't the easiest venue to participate in on a very occasional basis.

Comment: @RufusL Hmmm, I get:

Error 1 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Duration' and no extension method 'Duration' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RufusL Still no joy:

Error 1 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Duration' and no extension method 'Duration' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

But I'm so close I can taste it ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that it's a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`. In that case you would need to apply this to the `Value` property (which returns a `TimeSpan` from the `TimeSpan?`): `var absoluteDiff = (auth.First() - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Value.Duration().TotalMinutes;`

Comment: @RufusL I have to duck out but that appears to be the answer!!! I'll report back shortly...

Comment: @RufusL … I just wanted you to know it was perfect, and I'm deeply grateful.  This place always makes me feel like I've got my tail between my legs and I sincerely appreciate your help and congeniality.

Comment: Glad it worked out! The good thing is you can give back to the community as you grow; everyone starts out with their "tail between their legs" :)